# Using all components that have been built by React and .NET core 3.1 in Sitefinity

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, sitefinity

If I have a project consists of React as Front-end and .NET Core 3.1 as Backend How could I convert it for the Sitefinity project because I don't want to use asp.net MVC because that will need to rebuild all Old component by using Sitefinity, I want to use the old components as it's and build any new component by Sitefinity . so Is there any way to do that or I need to rebuild everything by Sitefinity.

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely have to use Sitefinity's OData web services functionality if you don't want to rebuild it all using cshtml Razor views.

This link and the links it contains may help:
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-use-Sitefinity-as-Headless-CMS

I'd personally just rebuilt it using Razor views though as Sitefinity was primarily designed as a Traditional/Monolithic CMS.